# Can Blender build proxy files with transparency?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm editing multiple sequences of png with transparency, but the preview is very slow (8fps).
I tried to use proxies, but it seems that Blender can only generate jpeg files with black background.
Is there a way to use png files as proxies?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I've found this solution:

### Blender looks for jpeg files, but actually you can use PNG files with .jpg extension.

This is my workflow:

**1. Create resized copies of the render images:**

25% > 1920 x 1080 -> **480** x 270

**2. Change all the extensions from .png to .jpg**

Assuming that the render path was:

```
/User/render/def/barca/b.png
```

the Proxy Directory in the VSE Panel was

```
/User/render/proxy/
```

I've used **ffmpeg** to create a scaled copy of the render files.

Open terminal (I'm on Mac) and type:

```
cd /User/render/

ffmpeg -i def/barca/b-%04d.png -vf scale=480:-1 proxy/images/25/b-%04d.png_proxy.png
```

than rename all the files

```
cd proxy/images/25/
for old in *.png; do mv $old `basename $old .png`.jpg; done
```

(thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887275/changing-file-extensions-for-all-files-in-a-directory-osx)

Here's a rough script that sets all the strips

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
C.scene.sequence_editor.proxy_storage = 'PROJECT'

C.scene.sequence_editor.proxy_dir = '/path/for/proxy/'

seq = C.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all
for s in seq:
    s.use_proxy = True
    s.proxy.use_overwrite = False

    # I ONLY NEED PROXY 25%
    s.proxy.build_25 = True
```